# more stable version of trigger by scroll point (jQuery / JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, screen-resolution

The below works.. for the most part.

It resolves correctly on smaller monitors and laptops... correctly trigger elements to fade in on scroll point. PROBLEM. iMacs and large resolutions -- the scroll point isn't really read, because the anchor height isn't hit because the screen is so large. Any suggestions at having the below feature work on larger resolutions as well? Declaring a % somehow? Anything more stable to try?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1800 && !breakpoint ) {
     // doStuff();
    // alert('Breakpoint 1500');
    $('.updated').delay(700).fadeIn(2000);
    $('#own_1').delay(700).fadeIn(2000);
    $('#own_2').delay(800).fadeIn(2100);
    $('#own_3').delay(900).fadeIn(2200);
    $('#buy_1').delay(1000).fadeIn(2300);
    $('#shop_1').delay(1100).fadeIn(2400);
    $('#shop_2').delay(1200).fadeIn(2500);
    $('#shop_3').delay(1300).fadeIn(2600);
  }
})
```

Comment: Off topic but I usually use Waypoints.js for this stuff. http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ Makes it really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Declare some variables to reuse them
var $window = $(window),
    $document = $(document),
    limit = 1800;

// Create your function
function myFunction(){
  if (// If we scroll over the limit OR if the window is too high to scroll to the limit
       ($window.scrollTop() > limit || $window.height() >= $document.height() - limit)
       &&
       // AND breakpoint is false
       !breakpoint
   ){
      // Note that for performance you should store these elements in variables
      // oustide this function to avoid searching for them on every call.
      $('.updated').delay(700).fadeIn(2000);
      $('#own_1').delay(700).fadeIn(2000);
      $('#own_2').delay(800).fadeIn(2100);
      $('#own_3').delay(900).fadeIn(2200);
      $('#buy_1').delay(1000).fadeIn(2300);
      $('#shop_1').delay(1100).fadeIn(2400);
      $('#shop_2').delay(1200).fadeIn(2500);
      $('#shop_3').delay(1300).fadeIn(2600);
  }
}

// Bind the function to scroll and resize event
$window.scroll(myFunction).resize(myFunction);

// Execute the function once on load,
// in case the user can't scroll to that point
// and does not resize their browser window
myFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But this didn't work at all -- under any resolution!

Comment: It works for me. What happens when you try, does it not get executed, or do you have any errors in the console? Is breakpoint set to false? (Required for the if statement to be executed)

Comment: thanks so much for the reply and suggestion! After implementing this code in my .JS file the fade in never occurs, any suggestions? here is my full .js file with your suggestion included: http://jsfiddle.net/jmj8ac67/